# How can I access attribute on parent container when using event listener?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I've attached an event listener to a container element. I have added a data attribute to the container element and am consoleing out the data attribute when I click the container, so that works great. I can see that it also fires the event listener when I click on any children inside the container, but then I can't get the data attribute. Any ideas how I can get the container's data attribute when a child is clicked?

See it in action here: https://js-addeventlistener-demo.stackblitz.io

**HTML:**

```
<div class="group">
  <div class="container" data-letter="A">
    <h2>A</h2>
    <span>Subtitle</span>
  </div>

  <div class="container" data-letter="B">
    <h2>B</h2>
    <span>Subtitle</span>
  </div>

  <div class="container" data-letter="C">
    <h2>C</h2>
    <span>Subtitle</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
const containers = document.querySelectorAll('div.container');

containers.forEach(container => {
  container.addEventListener('click', e => {
    console.dir(e.target);
    console.log('The dataset letter for the container element is', e.target.dataset.letter);
  });
});
```

Comment: (e.target.dataset.letter!=undefined) ? ""+e.target.dataset.letter : ""+e.target.parentElement.dataset.letter

Comment: change e.target.dataset.letter to container.parentNode.getAttribute("data-letter");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to event [bubbling](https://medium.com/@vsvaibhav2016/event-bubbling-and-event-capturing-in-javascript-6ff38bec30e) you're getting all of the clicks from the container as well any event by the children elements.

The `target` event property refers to the element that triggered the event, not the container itself (expect the direct clicks on the container).

You should use the `currentTarget` event property which refers to the element on which the listener is attached.

```
containers.forEach(container => {
  container.addEventListener('click', e => { 
    console.log(
      'The dataset letter for the container element is', 
      e.currentTarget.dataset.letter
    );
  });
});
```

Comment: Your answer was awesome! Thanks! I did notice, however, that I am not seeing it happen multiple times due to bubbling. It only ever fires the console.log() once. Is that expected? I thought it would happen every time it hits a new node on the DOM tree.

Comment: The event hits every element, starting from the element you clicked then it traverses up the DOM tree. In order to observe this you have to attach listener to the element you want to grab the click event. For your example if you attach an additional listener to some child element, and for example to the `document` element you'll see that three of them will be triggered when clicking on the container's child element. I've just found some site with live demos: https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing

Answer (score 1):

You can get the target and check if the target has class `container` using `classList.contains`. If not then use `closest` to get the closest div with container class. For example if you click on the container(green border) the `classList.contains` will return true since it have class. But clicking on h2 or span which does not have the class container will get the closest `container` using closest

```js
const containers = document.querySelectorAll('div.container');

containers.forEach(container => {
  container.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('container')) {
      console.log(e.target.dataset.letter);
    } else {
      let getClosestContainer = e.target.closest('.container');
      console.log(getClosestContainer.dataset.letter)

    }

  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

h2 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

span {
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
  <div class="container" data-letter="A">
    <h2>A</h2>
    <span>Subtitle</span>
  </div>

  <div class="container" data-letter="B">
    <h2>B</h2>
    <span>Subtitle</span>
  </div>

  <div class="container" data-letter="C">
    <h2>C</h2>
    <span>Subtitle</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your solution is more generic. thanks got to know the alternate way

Answer (score 1):

you can a condition check like this

**if `e.target.dataset.letter`  is undefined the you can check for parent element.**

```
containers.forEach(container => {
  container.addEventListener('click', e => {
    console.dir(e.target);
    console.log('The dataset letter for the container element is', (e.target.dataset.letter!=undefined) ? ""+e.target.dataset.letter : ""+e.target.parentElement.dataset.letter);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can access to `container` from `foreach argument`

```js
const containers = document.querySelectorAll('div.container');

containers.forEach(container => {
  container.addEventListener('click', e => {
    console.dir(e.target);
    console.log('The dataset letter for the container element is', container.dataset.letter);
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="group">
  <div class="container" data-letter="A">
    <h2>A</h2>
    <span>Subtitle</span>
  </div>

  <div class="container" data-letter="B">
    <h2>B</h2>
    <span>Subtitle</span>
  </div>

  <div class="container" data-letter="C">
    <h2>C</h2>
    <span>Subtitle</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I love this solution! Thanks!